# problems installing numpy for python 3.5

Tags: python, numpy, module

I have been trying for over 2 hours to install numpy module for python 3.5

for some reason i keep getting this error at the end

```
building library "npymath" sources
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

I read a lot about this problem from other people. but can't seem to figure out how to fix it for me.

i Have:

Microsoft Visual c++ 2013 Redistributable

Microsoft Visual c++ 2012 Redistributable

Microsoft Visual c++ 2010 Redistributable

any help will be good!

Thanks

p.s this is the full output

```
C:\David\Temp Files\numpy-1.10.1>python setup.py install
Running from numpy source directory.
C:\Users\David\Python35\lib\distutils\dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'test_suite'
  warnings.warn(msg)
blas_opt_info:
blas_mkl_info:
  libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['C:\\Users\\David\\Python35\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\David\\Python35\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

openblas_info:
  libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\David\\Python35\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\David\\Python35\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries tatlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\David\\Python35\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\David\\Python35\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_blas_info:
  libraries satlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\David\\Python35\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\David\\Python35\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\David\\Python35\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\David\\Python35\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_info:
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\David\\Python35\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\David\\Python35\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\David\Temp Files\numpy-1.10.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1651: UserWarning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
blas_info:
  libraries blas not found in ['C:\\Users\\David\\Python35\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\David\\Python35\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\David\Temp Files\numpy-1.10.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1660: UserWarning:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
    the BLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
blas_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\David\Temp Files\numpy-1.10.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1663: UserWarning:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
    the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
  warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
  NOT AVAILABLE

non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
F2PY Version 2
lapack_opt_info:
openblas_lapack_info:
  libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\David\\Python35\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\David\\Python35\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

lapack_mkl_info:
mkl_info:
  libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['C:\\Users\\David\\Python35\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\David\\Python35\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\David\Python35\lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\David\Python35\lib
  libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\David\Python35\libs
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\David\Python35\libs
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_info:
  libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\David\Python35\lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\David\Python35\lib
  libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\David\Python35\libs
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\David\Python35\libs
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\David\Python35\lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\David\Python35\lib
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\David\Python35\libs
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\David\Python35\libs
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_info:
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\David\Python35\lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\David\Python35\lib
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\David\Python35\libs
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\David\Python35\libs
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\David\Temp Files\numpy-1.10.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1552: UserWarning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
lapack_info:
  libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\David\\Python35\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\David\\Python35\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\David\Temp Files\numpy-1.10.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1563: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
    the LAPACK environment variable.
  warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
lapack_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\David\Temp Files\numpy-1.10.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1566: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
  warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\David\Python35\lib\distutils\dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
  warnings.warn(msg)
C:\Users\David\Python35\lib\distutils\dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'test_suite'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running install
running build
running config_cc
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
running build_src
build_src
building py_modules sources
building library "npymath" sources
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

Comment: Have you tried installing numpy from the windows binaries [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs#numpy)? Also fwiw, this error is what caused me to switch to linux

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related with VisualStudio (default) installation.

While installing VS 2015 Community Version, you normally choose the default express installation, which DOES NOT INCLUDE LANGUAGE SUPPORT UTILITIES, including Python.

So you should include Programming Languages option in the installation menu at the very beginning. Otherwise the VC2015 is installed but the Python support is not.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm the Python support in MSVC is not needed to build NumPy - it is just an interface to let you edit Python files using MSVC if you love Visual Studio.  NumPy actually uses just the C++ compiler.  `vcvarsall.bat` just sets the environment variables for MSVC builds for you as a convenience function, which NumPy couldn't find while you were trying to build.  I take it you were trying to make a custom installation?  OpenBlas or something?  Just download a binary online you can find ATLAS builds and MKL http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy , then you save yourself the hassle of building from source (and it is a MAJOR hassle in my opinion)... Oh BTW you can't install any packages for Python 3.5 using Visual Studio 2013, it is built using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 so just download the 2015 community version if going that route https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx  You'll also need it anytime you compile a package with `python setup.py install`